# CSS Background not working on Codepen

Tags: html, css, codepen

I've been trying to put my code up on Codepen but for some reason, the #left div background just doesn't display. It however, works fine locally. I've tried using image urls, background colors and everything to fix it, but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be appreciated!

Only the #left div is supposed to have a background color.
Following is the code and [here's the codepen.](https://codepen.io/scribbyx/pen/yPWbbq)

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<body>
  <div id="left">
  <form id="formBox">
    <textarea id="input" placeholder="Enter your LispyHTML"></textarea>
    <input id="renderButton" type="button" onclick="render()" value="Render!">
  </form>
</div>
    <div id="right">
  <div id="target">
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

style.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#left{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  background: #000000 !important;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);       */
}

#right{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

#formBox{
    position: absolute;
    width:40vw;
    height:240px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    left:20%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-17%;
    margin-top:-200px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#target{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-style: none; 
    border-color: Transparent; 
    overflow: auto; 
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    display:inline-block

}

#renderButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 37%;
    background-color:#9C27B0;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #9C27B0;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-size:17px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
    outline: none;
}
#renderButton:hover {
    background-color:#7B1FA2;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Your `background` rule for the specified element `#left` is applying, you can verify this by inspecting the element in question. When doing so, you may also notice that this element has no calculated height, you have used a *percentage unit* value which is supposed to be *relative* to a more explicitly defined *length unit* value (with *absolute* values defined in, for example, `px`) - of which there is none. Defining any absolute `height` value, on `#left`, using a *length unit* will demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change height 100% to 100vh

```
#left{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    background: #000000 !important;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);       */
}
```

or

`#formBox` change position:relative and margin-top:0px